# Send data to flask without reloading the page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm currently writing an application where the user can select some ingredients and add them to the meal. The user selects the ingredients one-at-a-time through a `<select>` element (the options are based on the ingredients that are currently available in the database). The entire goal is to have a single page where the user can create and submit a full meal, including the ingredients.

How do I send the item that the user has selected to a python variable without reloading the entire page (and thus losing all the other data on the page)?